# How to set "no-unused-vars": "off" in babel config?

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

I have a vue.js and want to disable the unsed var error. My babel config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

Where can add I add custom options? I read this doc https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eslint you can configure rules in your eslint config

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    rules: {
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
}
```

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/